# How could I loop this for loop over all items?

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, automation

Basically this `for loop` is supposed to work if a dropdown menu is shown on the page. I could've made it work just for one item of the list, but could not make it loop over all the dropdown items.

How could I make It work for all the dropdown items?

```
# IF THE DROPDOWN IS SHOWED
if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/span').is_displayed():
    qntbenef = 'SIM'
    print('Mais de um beneficio')

    # DROPDOWN CLICK TO MAKE ITEMS VISIBLE
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/span').click()

    # DROPDOWN LIST = DROPD
    dropd = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/ul')

    # EACH ITEM IN DROPDOWN LIST
    benefs = range(len(dropd))

    # PRINT AND LOOP FOR EACH ITEM
    for self.benef in benefs:
        print(dropd[self.benef].text)

        dropd[self.benef].click()

        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/main[1]/div[@id='dashboard'][not(contains(@class, 'left hide'))]"
            "/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text

        print(nome)
```

The `print(dropd[self.benef].text)` works well and print all the items, but the rest of the code only works for the first item of the list...

Comment: Could you give us a minimal working example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: After the code I said: "The `print(dropd[self.benef].text)` works well and print all the items, but the rest of the code only works for the first item of the list..."

Comment: As far as I understand, when `dropd[self.benef].click()` is executed, the first element in the dropdown is selected and all other elements aren't available for clicking. @MoisesFelipe what logic do you want to implement\?